# Aggregate SQL group by counts based on group by

Tags: sql, group-by, case

I have a query as such (which doesn't quite work as intended)

```
SELECT 
(CASE 
    WHEN str LIKE '%some_string%' THEN 's'
    WHEN str LIKE '%some_string2%' THEN 's2'
END) as str,
COUNT(*) as num FROM Table WHERE
str LIKE '%some_string%' or
str LIKE '%some_string2%'
group by str
```

and the table contains things like

```
|      str                       |
|------------------------------- |
| "some_string_a;"               |  
| "some_string_b; some_else"     |  
| "some_string_c; some_else"     |  
| "some_else; some_string2a"     |  
| "some_string_c; some_string2b" |
```

How do I get a result like the following?

```
|      str      |   num  |
|---------------|--------|
| s             |   4    |
| s2            |   2    |
```

I currently I'm undercounting because rows 1,2,3, and 5 are counted as 'some_string%' (and hence 's') when they actually contain both.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without getting *extremely* complicated - would it be acceptable to have the values come back in columns instead of rows? That may be a good result for the amount of effort required unless you absolutely need it to be this way.

Comment: @rio can you please check my answer??

Comment: You must normalize your data at first.

Comment: @eouw0o83hf I think that's Alden's approach below, correct?

Comment: @Rio yep. That's going to give you a much easier time if it's an acceptable response.

Answer (score 1):

my updated answer

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e10d5/1)**

Try this

```
    CREATE table Table1 (str varchar(50));


    Insert into Table1(str) values('aaa');
    Insert into Table1(str) values('bbb');
    Insert into Table1(str) values('aaaaaaaaaa');
    Insert into Table1(str) values('bbbbbbbbbb');
    Insert into Table1(str) values('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
    Insert into Table1(str) values('aaabbbbb');
    Insert into Table1(str) values('ccccccccccccccc');


Select str , count(*) from
(
    SELECT 
    (CASE  
    WHEN str LIKE '%bbb%' THEN 's2'
    WHEN str LIKE '%aaa%' THEN 's'     
    END) as str
    FROM Table1 WHERE
    str LIKE '%aaa%' or
    str LIKE '%bbb%'
) as T group by str; -- will count in s2 means in a so s will be 3 and s2 is 3
```

Comment: It doesn't work for the case Insert into Table1(str) values('aaabbbbb');

Comment: of if i insert aaabbbb in which it should count whether in s or in s2 .. i think as per you it should count in s2 so both values 3 in my example (after inserting aaabbbb) .. right ??

Comment: It should both be 3, but your SQLFiddle returns 3 and 2 (change the first row to be aaabbbbb)

Comment: I think aaa should be counted 4 times, no?

Comment: so do u mean s is 4 and s2 will be 3 ??? in that case Alden's ersponse is the only way i think

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the Order of the conditions in your CASE statement.

```
SELECT 
(CASE 
    WHEN str LIKE '%some_string2%' THEN 's2'
    WHEN str LIKE '%some_string%' THEN 's'
END) as str,
COUNT(*) as num FROM Table WHERE
str LIKE '%some_string%' or
str LIKE '%some_string2%'
group by str
```

Comment: I don't think that handles the "two instances of some_string in a single row" case, though - that was my initial thought :p

Comment: It would not handle two instance of some_string in a single row, you're right.  But it does solve the problem of the row counting words s when it should go toward s2. To handle the issue you bring up, I would probably create a UDF that returns an int of the number of times a pattern occurs in another string/row.  Then we could just SUM those.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
SELECT SUM(IF(str LIKE '%some_string%',1,0)) AS s,
       SUM(IF(str LIKE '%some_string2%',1,0)) AS s2
FROM Table WHERE
str LIKE '%some_string%' or
str LIKE '%some_string2%'
group by str;
```

Comment: This creates additional columns, I think, but then I guess I'd have to sort by s, s2 and I wouldn't know beforehand which columns are more like (so it could be that sort by s2, s is better).

Answer (score 0):

You want to group by the same expression in the `select`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN str LIKE '%some_string%' THEN 's'
             WHEN str LIKE '%some_string2%' THEN 's2'
        END) as str,
       COUNT(*) as num
FROM Table
WHERE str LIKE '%some_string%' or
      str LIKE '%some_string2%'
group by (CASE WHEN str LIKE '%some_string%' THEN 's'
               WHEN str LIKE '%some_string2%' THEN 's2'
          END);
```

Some databases allow a column alias (`str`) to be used in `group by`, but not all.  You are safer using the complete expression or using a subquery (as suggested by Dhaval).  However, I would write it as:

```
select str, count(*)
from (select (CASE WHEN str LIKE '%some_string%' THEN 's'
                   WHEN str LIKE '%some_string2%' THEN 's2'
              END) as str
      from table
     ) t
where str is not null
group by str;
```

You don't have to repeat the comparisons, because `str` gets a `NULL` value when it doesn't match either.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the group by (CASE WHEN str LIKE '%some_string%' THEN 's'
               WHEN str LIKE '%some_string2%' THEN 's2'
          END); bit. I need to do Group by str, but group by (CASE WHEN str LIKE '%some_string%' THEN 's'
               WHEN str LIKE '%some_string2%' THEN 's2'
          END) as str doesn't seem to play nicely.

Comment: What kind of trouble?  And what database are you using?  This is standard ANSI syntax.

Answer (score 0):

With **Postgres**, a general solution for `n` patterns might look like this:

```
SELECT p.pattern, count((str1 LIKE '%' || p.pattern || '%') OR NULL) AS  ct
FROM  (
   SELECT regexp_split_to_table(str, ';') AS str1
   FROM tbl
   ) x
CROSS  JOIN (
   VALUES ('some_string')
         ,('some_string2')
         -- more?
   ) AS p(pattern)
GROUP  BY p.pattern
```

Result:

```
pattern       | ct
--------------+----
some_string   | 6
some_string2  | 2
```

[**-> SQLfiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f38da/1)

- I **assume** you want to match each part of the string, delimited by `;`. The Postgres function `regexp_split_to_table()` normalizes your data in that way.
- I also **assume** you want to count every match with any pattern and not stop after the firs match.

A `CASE` statement would only yield a single match and suppress the rest. So I assume you do *not* want that.

Instead, I cross join to a `VALUES` expression that supplies as many patterns as you want. Very convenient for general use. You could use a table or subquery to provide the patterns in place of the `VALUES` expression.

Comment: It's an elegant solution but unfortunately the data isn't actually so clean, so the ; assumption actually breaks down. Thanks though!

Comment: I can only answer the question as it's given.